# Learning Image Processing/Computer Vision

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

What do I need to learn dense correspondence? 
I am a newbie in Image processing/CV.
Please help me by suggesting a kind of syllabus or show me a way to learn about Dense Matching. What are the things I really need to work on it.

Comment: Are you talking about optical flow?  What is the overall problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Basically, I want to work on this[http://vision.cs.utexas.edu/projects/dsp/]
Please suggest me a list of topic which i really need to learn to work on this. Or any kind of suggestion would be appreciated.